# Htaccess rewrite rules method get

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi i want rewrite:

example.com/articles to example.com/?rt=articles

and

example.com/articles/some-title-here to example.com/?rt=articles&title=some-title-here

My code:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ index.php?rt=articles&title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

First rewrite rule it's working but second doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes

# ignore all files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^articles/(.+)$ index.php?rt=articles&title=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Phew, you're too fast. ;-)